# Как сделать плавающую разметку на сайте

Tags: html, css

```
Добрый день. 
Хочу сделать разметку на сайте, что б  
-верхняя часть сайта была на всю ширину и не прокручивалась(была видна всегда)
-левая часть сайта была на всю высоту и не прокручивалась
-нижняя часть сайта была на всю ширину и не прокручивалась
-оставшаяся часть занимала оставшееся пространство,где бы был скролбар и прокручивалась.
```

Пример http://jsfiddle.net/devacademy/zEGF9/1/

```
Что-то голову ломаю-не могу сделать.
Спасибо большое.
```

Comment: А что не получается? Шапку, подвал и сайдбар фиксируете. В итоге, должно получится [что-то вроде этого][1]. Только мой пример рассматривайте именно, как "*пример*", а не готовое в употребление решение!

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/zEGF9/5/

Answer (score 1):

для трех блоков нужно использовать position:fixed, он зафиксирует вам хедер, левый блок и футер